# focus on an input that is located inside another component in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, onfocus

I would like to be able to focus on input field when certain keys are entered. The input I would like to focus on exists inside autocomplete-vue.
This is where I call it:

```
<autocomplete v-shortkey="['alt', 's']"
              @shortkey.native="theAction()"
              ref="autocompleteInput" 
></autocomplete>
```

theAction method which I would like to allow me to focus on the input, looks like this:

```
theAction () {
      this.$refs.autocompleteInput.$el.focus()
    }
```

this focus on the whole section which is not what I want. the input exists 2 divs inside the what theAction focuses on. For bettere perspective, this is what `this.$refs.autocompleteInput.$el` returns :

```
<div>
  <div data-position="below" class="autocomplete"> 
     <input role="combobox" class="autocomplete-input"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can focus on the input with class autocomplete-input? any suggestion is helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a ref in the `autocomplete` component for the `<input>` and add a method to focus it

```html
<input role="combobox" class="autocomplete-input" ref="input">
```

```js
methods: {
  focus() {
    this.$refs.input.focus()
  }
}
```

You can then call it from the parent component like this

```js
this.$refs.autocompleteInput.focus()
```